# Node.js - using Multer How to Get Upload file's(Source file's) full path?

Tags: node.js

I want to get uploading file's full path, as dynamic like a image, in my node.js code.

I don't know what to do, I need your help

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('userfile'), function(req, res){

  var filename = __dirname +'/'+ req.file.path; //this is uploaded file path
  var s = fs.ReadStream(filename);
  s.on('data', function(data) {
    shasum.update(data)
  })
  // making digest
  s.on('end', function() {
    var hash = shasum.digest('hex')
    console.log("Hash : "+ hash + '  ' + filename)
    res.send('Uploaded : ' + hash);
  })
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04ynz.png)

Comment: try this for full path **var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')+req.file.path;**

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodejs\example\http:\localhost:3000\uploads\4.4.1_번역.hwp'

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your comment, you are using local environment. Therefore the host will not lead to the full URL. So try removing the host.

So replace:

```
var filename = __dirname +'/'+ req.file.path;
```

With:

```
var filename = req.protocol + req.file.path;
```